# An adblocker rule list for "Update to our privacy policy" popups in light of GDPR

Tags: css, ad-blocker

I normally browse in private mode for various reasons, and I've already set up most of my frequently visited sites with a script which blocks new user popups.

GDPR has caused a lot of sites to show "We have updated our privacy policy" popups which is a pain to write a removal script for on so many sites. Is there a convenient ad blocker rule list for these (for use with Ublock Origin for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Although not GDPR-specific, *I Don’t Care About Cookies* removes cookie warnings on websites. It is available as an adblock filter list or a separate extension.

https://www.i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu/

Comment: beside that one some additional (prioritized) may be useful:  
https://fanboy.co.nz/fanboy-cookiemonster.txt  **||** 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r4vi/block-the-eu-cookie-shit-list/master/filterlist.txt  **||**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liamja/Prebake/master/obtrusive.txt  **||**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rudloff/adblock-imokwithcookies/master/filters.txt